# ones mouse over entire galary will be hover with text in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

![enter image description here][1]i have a problem in my image gallery i want to hover four images at the same time ones mouse over one of those image. can i do this job and how i do this please give me a proper answer.

here is my html code

```
                <!--Page Navigation-->
                <!--Page Navigation End-->

            <div class="home-block" >

                <div class="one-third-thumbs clearfix" >
                    <figure>
                        <figcaption>
                            <strong>WEDDINGS</strong>                       
                            <a href="gallery-Weddigs.html" class="opener"></a>
                        </figcaption>

                        <a href="gallery-Weddigs.html"  class="thumb"><img src="img/dummies/featured-1.jpg" alt="Alt text" /></a>
                    </figure>

                    <figure>
                        <figcaption>
                            <strong>STUDIO</strong>                         
                            <a href="gallery-Studio.html" class="opener"></a>
                        </figcaption>

                        <a href="gallery-Studio.html"  class="thumb"><img src="img/dummies/featured-2.jpg" alt="Alt text" /></a>
                    </figure>



                    <figure>
                        <figcaption>
                            <strong>COMMERCIAL</strong>                         
                            <a href="gallery-Commercial.html" class="opener"></a>
                        </figcaption>

                        <a href="gallery-Commercial.html"  class="thumb"><img src="img/dummies/featured-5.jpg" alt="Alt text" /></a>
                    </figure>

                    <figure class="last">
                        <figcaption>
                            <strong>VIDEO</strong>                      
                            <a href="gallery-Video.html" class="opener"></a>
                        </figcaption>

                        <a href="gallery-Video.html"  class="thumb"><img src="img/dummies/featured-6.jpg" alt="Alt text" /></a>
                    </figure>


                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: please give us a proper question before to ask for a proper answer :D how would you want to hover several elements at the same time ?

Comment: i have four images and i added separate links to each one. now if i move on top of the image hovers that image only i want to hover four of them at the same time with text.

Comment: what means "hover" for you : is it a cursor event or a visual change of the elements ? how are you trying to achieve it : through CSS or Javascript ? please provide the according code.

Comment: give me any of the answer css of javascript.

Comment: if you want someone to do the whole job for you, I can send you my rates in a private message

Answer (score 0):

Please See This Demos

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m5f8h/)

```
<style>
span.hover-txt { display:none; }
a:hover+span.hover-txt { display:block!important; }
</style>

<a href="gallery-Weddigs.html"  class="thumb"><img src="img/dummies/featured-1.jpg" alt="Alt text" /></a>
<span class="hover-txt"> Your Text Here </span>
```